# Every divergence-free vector field generated from skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: real-analysis, vector-fields

> Let $[a_{i,j}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)]$ be a skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix of functions $a_{i,j}\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The vector field $$v=\sum\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}a_{i,j}\right)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$$ [is divergence-free](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578553/divergence-free-vector-field-from-skew-symmetric-matrix).
>
> Prove by induction that for every $n\geq 2$, every $C^\infty$ divergence-free vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of this form.

Consider $n=2$. Suppose the vector field is $f_1(x_1,x_2)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+f_2(x_1,x_2)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$. Since the vector field is divergence-free, we have that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f_1(x_1,x_2)+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_2}f_2(x_1,x_2)=0$. By [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578709/converse-of-interchanging-order-for-derivatives), there exists a function $g(x_1,x_2)$ whose $x_1$-derivative equals $f_2$ and whose $x_2$-derivative equals $-f_1$. The result follows.

But how about for $n>2$? To use induction, I have to relate a divergence-free vector field of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a divergence-free vector field of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. It is possible that the following [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578585/subtracting-off-first-coordinate-to-get-divergence-free-vector-field) will help:

> Let $v$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $v$ can be written as a sum $v=f_1\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+w$ where $w$ is a divergence-free vector field.

Comment: The case $n=3$ is the result that says if $\text{div}(u) = 0$, then $u = \text{curl} v$ for some vector $v$.

Comment: Also the case $n=2$ was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578709/converse-of-interchanging-order-for-derivatives/578729#578729 - think of $(-h,g)$ as the divergence free vector field, and $\pm \frac12 f$ as the off diagonal entries of the skew matrix.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Yes, exactly. I wrote that the case $n=2$ was taken care of by that link. What I'm stuck is jumping from $n-1$ to $n$ for the induction.

Comment: Today is very busy for me, so I probably won't have time to think of a solution.  But in view of the previous questions you asked, and their relationship to this problem, it makes sense to think "anti-derivative."

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your $n=2$ comment.  Hey, here is a way that I find helpful.  Instead of working with the functions directly, work with their Fourier transforms.  Then the condition that $v$ is divergence free becomes $k \cdot \vat v(k) = 0$, where $k \in \mathbb R^n$ is sometimes called the wavenumber.  So in the 3D case, you want to conclude that there exists a vector $v$ such that $\hat u = k \times \hat v$.  This reduces the whole problem to vector algebra (e.g. in this case try $v = -k\times \hat u$.)  Once you have the algebra worked out, it should tell you where to apply anti-derivs.

Comment: On the other hand, my previous remark might also be misleading.  Because in the $n=3$ case you end up having to solve $|k|^2 \hat w = \hat f$, and this means solving the Laplacian equation.  This can be done, but it obviously isn't the intent of this exercise.  On the other hand, it will give you insight into the Hodge decomposition, and my guess is that this is where your studies are taking you.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I wouldn't think that's the intended way to go. My study is just about a manifold version of the divergence theorem -- there shouldn't be anything to do with Fourier transforms.

Comment: I'm curious about two points: 1. Where is your question from? 2.Why do you have to use induction?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang 1. It's from a lecture note for a course on manifolds. 2. The question is stated that way, so I presume it's the intended way.

Comment: @JJBeck Thanks. I would love to read that lecture note if applications for this kind of vector fields are mentioned therein.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang I only have a hard copy of it. Maybe I'll upload it when I have time.

Comment: @JJBeck Could I interrupt you one minute? Let's chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11802/discussion-between-shuchang-zhang-and-jj-beck) if you are available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Induction Hypothesis over $k$:** Given a smooth divergence free vector field $v:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\text{div}_{k} v := \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i} = 0$, there exists a smooth skew-symmetric matrix $a:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ such that $v_j = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac\partial{\partial x_i} a_{ij}$ for $1 \le i \le k$.

The case $k=0$ is trivial.

Suppose it is true for $k-1 \ge 0$.  We prove it for $k$.

Let
$$ f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \int_0^{x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} v_k(\xi,x_2,x_1,\dots,x_n) \, d\xi .$$
Then
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(v_1+f_1) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}v_2 + \dots + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k-1}}v_{k-1} = 0 .$$

By the inductive hypothesis, there is a skew symmetric matrix $a_{ij}$ such
$$ v_1 + f_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} a_{i1} $$
$$ v_j = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} a_{ij} \quad \text{ for $2 \le j \le k-1$}$$

We define
$$ f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \int_0^{x_1} v_k(\xi,x_2,\dots,x_{k-1},0,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n) \, d\xi - \int_0^{x_k} f_1(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},\xi,\dots,x_n) \, d\xi .$$
Then 
$$ \frac\partial{\partial x_1} f_2 = v_k(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},0,\dots,x_n) - \int_0^{x_k} \frac\partial{\partial x_k} v_k(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},\xi,\dots,x_n) \, d\xi = -v_k $$
and
$$ \frac\partial{\partial x_k} f_2 = - f_1 $$
Now extend the matrix $a$ by setting $a_{k1} = -a_{1k} = f_2$, and $a_{kj}=a_{jk} = 0$ for $2 \le j \le k$.
Then
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} a_{i1} = v_1 + f_1 + \frac\partial{\partial x_k} f_2 = v_1, $$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} a_{j1} = v_j \quad \text{ for $2 \le j \le k-1$}, $$
and
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} a_{ik} = - \frac\partial{\partial x_1} f_2  = v_k. $$

Comment: Hmm.. I think the inductive hypothesis only holds if you know $v_1-f_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ are functions of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}$, but here they're also functions of $x_n$.

Comment: That's why you fix $x_n$ so that you can apply it separately for each $x_n$.

Comment: Why will the resulting matrix have non-zero entries only in the first column or the first row? I can't see that...

Comment: Because at the $n$th induction step, all I added was entries in the $(1,n)$ and $(n,1)$ positions to the prior $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix.

Comment: For 100 points, I'll put in some more details.  I have to pick up my kids right now.  So I'll get to it later.

Comment: @JJBeck How about this updated answer?

Comment: I must say that the Montgomery-Smith answers are always high quality.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since induction is mentioned, I'd like to give a try. Note that
$$\nabla\cdot v=\sum_{i,j}^n\partial_i(\partial_ja_{ij})=\sum_{i,j}^{n-1}\partial_i(\partial_ja_{ij})+\sum_i^{n-1}\partial_i(\partial_na_{in})+\sum_j^{n-1}\partial_n(\partial_ja_{nj})=0$$
Wow... It seems easier than what I've thought.

Comment: I'm confused - we're asked to show that the $a_{ij}$ exist, so how can you assume their existence in the first place? Or maybe I misunderstood your argument.

Comment: @JJBeck As I mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578709/converse-of-interchanging-order-for-derivatives/578750#578750), Poincare lemma gives the existence of such $A$.

Comment: Hmm okay. I appreciate your answer, but unfortunately it's way beyond the material I'm studying, so its use is limited for me.

Comment: This question is equivalent to the Poincare lemma. Treat vector field as one form, then divergence can be thought of as $d^*$ with the standard metric.